# Custom Module DB Variable Export - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, module

I've Got a Small Script That Runs Continuously On My Server.

I'd Like To Connect It To a DB To Get Some Data For The Script's Operation. **So, I Required The Custom Model I Built, And Node Recognises It** - It Does Not Send Back An Error With "Module Not Found".

The DB Script **Works**, And Pulls Exactly What I Need From The DB. This Is How It Looks (Assume The Connection Is Open - This Is Just The Query & Response Code):

```
connection.query(sql, function (err,rows){

//Handle Errors
if(err){
    throw err;
}

//If Successful - Log Results For Now (Change To Export Results)
else{
    //console.log(rows);
    rows = exports.rows;
}

});
```

Unfortunately, Whenever I Call `DB.rows` In My Main Script, It Returns `undefined`.

Am I Exporting It Wrong Or The Problem Lies Deeper Within?

Comment: can you provide the whole script?

Comment: Solved Here Already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817129/javascript-calling-a-variable-from-outside-of-if-else-block-returns-undefined