# Javascript - Calling A Variable From Outside Of If/Else Block Returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, global-variables

I thought [this is how you make a variable inside a if/else block global (Case 3).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

```
connection.query(sql, function (err,rows){

    //Handle Errors
    if(err){
        //Log The Error & Die
    }

    //If Successful - Log Results For Now (Change To Export Results)
    else {
        //console.log(rows);
        foo = rows;

    }

});

console.log(foo); // Out: undefined
```

Why can't I access the variable outside of the function?

**SOLUTION**

Well, the problem here was one of understanding what asynchronicity *really is*. After chatting with @AmmarCSE and [looking at this great question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323) I understood that I structured my question (and my code, obviously) incorrectly.

I was trying to access a variable that is not defined until the function finishes to run (an SQL query to a remote DB obviously takes longer to finish then running a local script). If I structure my code *asynchronically*, however, the variable *only gets called once the function finishes*.

This, as it turns out - is not a problem of variable *scope*, really, but of variable *defining time* (not sure if that's the correct terminology for the time in the script where the variables get defined - CS majors, feel free to edit in the correct term).

Anyway, Here is the new code:

```
runSQL(function(result){

//Do Whatever you want with the results - they're defined!!
console.log(result);
)};

function runSQL(callback){

connection.query(sql, function (err,rows){

        //Handle Errors
        if(err){
            //Log The Error & Die
        }

        //If Successful - Log Results For Now (Change To Export Results)
        else {
            callback(rows);            
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: You can, but callbacks don't execute when you think they do.

Comment: I KInda Pointed That As My Reference.

Comment: @DaveNewton How So? What Am I Missing Here?

Comment: I know I answered, but actually, **I** have a question. Shouldnt `foo` above still work because it is a global variable because it was defined without `var`?

Comment: @AmmarCSE - That's What I Said! Weird As Hell.

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake now. The callback is **asynchronous** therefore, when you log `foo` it is `undefined` because it was not defined yet in the callback

Comment: So How Can I Be Sure That When I Call The Variable It Will Be Defined?

Comment: @TomGranot-Scalosub, it depends on the flow of your code. When/why do you need foo? You should restructure your code around the asyncronous nature of the callback.

Comment: @AmmarCSE - This is a DB querying module I built to provide me with a certain record for my main app every time the app runs. So, I need to **export** the record from this module to my main module. *However,* I cannot do that from within the function.

Comment: @TomGranot-Scalosub, you will need to export from within the function. Call `export()` from within the callback itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80452/discussion-between-ammarcse-and-tom-granot-scalosub).

Comment: @TomGranot-Scalosub, join the chat so we can discuss in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in the `error callback`, it has its own scope defined. Therefore, `foo` is only **visible** to that closure and any nested closures. For case 3 you have mentioned in the link

```
var a = 1;

function four() {
  if (true) {
    var a = 4;
  }

  alert(a); // alerts '4', not the global value of '1'
}
```

they alert the variable within the correct closure, `function four()`, even if that variable was defined in the `if` block, it is visible to its parent function.

However, you are making `foo` **global** by not prefixing with `var`. Yet, logging after the callback results in `undefined` because at that point, `foo` was not yet defined. If you log within the error callback it will work but I advise you restructure your code to work with the **asynchronous** nature of callbacks

```
connection.query(sql, function (err,rows){

    //Handle Errors
    if(err){
        //Log The Error & Die
     }

    //If Successful - Log Results For Now (Change To Export Results)
    else{
        //console.log(rows);
        foo = rows;

    }
    console.log(foo);
    });
```

Comment: OK! But - I Need To Eventually Export That Variable Into A Different Module, And I **Can't** Do That From Within The Block. How Can I Make Sure `foo` Is Defined Outside Of `function` & `connection.query`?

Answer (score 0):

if you put a `var foo = "something"` in somewhere it'd would equal "something". I suppose it didn't go into the else otherwise it'd equal `rows`... Also is it possible `rows` is undefined?

Also without using a `var foo =` anywhere it becomes a global variable if the `foo =` bit is executed, which is probably not desirable...

Answer (score 0):

```
var result= connection.query(sql, function (err,rows){

    //Handle Errors
    if(err){
        //Log The Error & Die
     }

    //If Successful - Log Results For Now (Change To Export Results)
    else{
        //console.log(rows);
        document.foo = rows;

    }

    });

result.on('result', function(){
    console.log(document.foo);
}
```

Comment: It Throws Back That `window` is not defined.

Comment: sorry window is not used in nodejs, use document instead

Comment: First, this is node. Second, this isn't the issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry i dont see from the Q where globals are not the issue? Nodejs is only tagged below and i've updated to use document instead and a callback...

Comment: Scope isn't the issue, asynchronicity is. You edited after my comment; obviously if you change the answer's content a comment made prior to the edit won't necessarily make sense.